# TileGroup variable row count, column count, tile size, gap and left and right style properties

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, flex4.6

I am making a mobile application that will have on its home view a dashboard with a TileGroup. I would also like the tiles not fitting on the first screen to move to the next. This way I could slide the screen right and left. Basically, like the iPhone and iPad OS home screen where you can select the app you want to use.

To start I would like to  have the app arrange the vertical and horizontal gap between the tiles so it all fits the screen nicely.

Anyone has done this before or knows a reference link for a similar solution. Suggestions are very welcome.

Thanks,
Dave

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way you would do this is to show a subset of your dataprovider. On swipe, you would replace the dataprovider (or page it by using a filter function) on basis of page index.